# Notepad++ like "multi editing" in Vim?

Tags: vim, notepad++

I’m switching from Notepad++ to Vim as my main text editor.

In Notepad++, you can have multiple cursors by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking anywhere in the text, so that if you type, the text appears in multiple locations.

Is it possible in Vim? Something like insert after selecting multiple rows in Visual mode, but with the possibility to have cursors anywhere in the text.

It’s a feature I rarely use, and it’s also quite easily avoidable; I’m just curious, since it’s the only one I could’t find a replacement for in Vim yet.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of NP++ and nothing happens when I ctrl-click. I don't get two cursors.

Comment: yep, that has to be enabled under preferences/editing

Comment: Wow, that's kinda cool. I did not know that feature.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that feature either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a built-in feature of that kind.

Let me suggest a function that repeats command (for example `.` repeating last
change command) at the positions of given marks.  Both marks and command are
specified as string arguments.  Marks specified in the way ranges in regular
expressions or `scanf`-format specifier are defined.  For example, `za-dx`
means marks `z`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `x`.

```
function! MarksRepeat(marks, command)
    let pos = 0
    let len = strlen(a:marks)
    let alpha = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    let beta =  '1234567899bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZZ'
    while pos < len
        if a:marks[pos + 1] != '-'
            exe 'norm `' . a:marks[pos] . a:command
            let pos += 1
        elseif a:marks[pos] <= a:marks[pos+2]
            let mark = a:marks[pos]
            let stop = a:marks[pos+2]
            if mark =~ '[0-9a-zA-Z]' && stop =~ '[0-9a-zA-Z]'
                while 1
                    exe 'norm `' . mark . a:command
                    if mark == stop
                        break
                    endif
                    let mark = tr(mark, alpha, beta)
                endwhile
            endif
            let pos += 3
        endif
    endwhile
endfunction
```

In your case, the function could be used as follows.

1. Mark all places for simultaneous insertions (except one) using Vim
   marks (by means of `m` command).
2. Actually insert text in the one place that has not been marked.
3. Run the function:

   ```
   :call MarksRepeat(‹marks›, '.')
   ```

Comment: thanks, works fine. Im thinking of re-writing it, without using marks
(im a complete newb to programming vim so its gonna take some time, im not sure if its even possible, but thanks for getting me started!)

Comment: Interesting solution using marks.  Check out my solution that does not require a special function. (using `:folddoclosed`)

Answer (score 5):

You could insert the text in one place, in a single operation, then use `.` to repeat that insertion at each other place you want the text.

It's the converse of what you asked for, because you wanted to mark the locations before entering the text, but it gives you the same result in the same number of keystrokes :).

Answer (score 4):

Check multi select vim plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953

Answer (score 3):

ib's response and the multi select vim plugin are interesting, but the following is a suggestion that does not require a special function or plugin.

Temporarily `set foldmethod=manual`, then mark the blocks you want to operate on with `zf`.

Finally, use the ex command `:folddoclosed` to do ex commands on the folded blocks.

For example: `:folddoclosed norm Iinsert some text at the front`

Note, you can use `:folddoclosed` on any folded groups of lines, so you could use other foldmethods... but usually it makes sense to manually create the folds.

You can also use visual markers, followed by `:norm` which gives you `:'<,'>norm`... But visual markers only let you select a continuous range of lines.  Using folds and `:folddoclosed` you can operate on multiple ranges of lines at once.

Another tip... to save time having to type out `:folddoclosed`, I will type `:fo<shifttab><shifttab><shifttab>`

Comment: Using manual folds as markers is a very nice idea!  However, in contrast to the attempt with marks, here it is not possible to store particular positions on those lines, since folds are line-wise objects.  Anyway, multiple cursors do not match well with Vim editing model.